# Why is the add to cart button not working on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ajax

The add to cart button is not working on my product page, the following error shows up in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

This is the code on the add to basket button -

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Basket</span></span></button>
```

Having had a look I think I may have found the reason that it is not adding to cart. The form which the button submits has a different id to the actual form. Is this the reason for not submitting? And if so, how do I change this?

```
<form action="https://cbccomputers.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9jYmNjb21wdXRlcnMuY29tL3Bjcy1sYXB0b3BzLXRhYmxldHMvY29tcHV0ZXJzL3Bjcy9kZWxsLXZvc3Ryby0zMjY4LWkzLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/61297/form_key/Qj8R0mDVuAViFpbP/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form">
```

Relatively new to Magento and developing so any advice is helpful as it is quite urgent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change code from the original

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Basket</span></span></button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" ><span><span>Add to Basket</span></span></button>
```

Comment: Yes you need to change code in  app\design\frontend\themefolder\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

Comment: themefolder  means your theme path in your site

Comment: Hi, yes I am in the view.phtml file I was just wondering which bit of the code I change once I am in the view.phtml as I don't know PHP. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint   visit this and enalble template path hint.

Comment: after this path where you have to change code is there

Comment: folllow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint   to enable template path

Comment: Hi, Yes I've found the view.phtml file what I mean is once I have opened this file where do I make the code changes? @jigsparmar

Comment: give me file code

Comment: You Welcome and thank for accepting my answer.

Comment: @jigsparmar Same i am faced the issue, my error https://imgur.com/ZCxaxqq and https://imgur.com/j9syQgU could you pls help me to solve the issue?

Comment: you have used ajax method for add to cart

Comment: some third parth extension causes the issue